chroma sqlite3 version not properly updating in python
I am using a python virtual environment, which is set to Python 3.10.15. One of the packages I need to use is from langchain_chroma, specifically the Chroma class. The issue is that when running this import statement, I get the error below
RuntimeError: Your system has an unsupported version of sqlite3. Chroma                     requires sqlite3 >= 3.35.0.
This prevents me from being able to run the necessary code in my virtual enviroment.
I followed the instructions used given in the error, which sends me to this link https://docs.trychroma.com/troubleshooting#sqlite
Here, I did pip install pysqlite3-binary and still did not get a fix. Instead, my sqlite3 version is 3.31.1
The code I am running is from a team project, and everyone's virtual environment (some of which are a lower python 3.10 version than me), is able to run the code fine. I also compared my pip freeze output, and we either have the same version, or I have a more updated package version.
I have no idea what's going on at this point, and would love help as to how I can fix this problem

Did you override the sqlite as mentioned here in init.py?
https://gist.github.com/defulmere/8b9695e415a44271061cc8e272f3c300
